# Грамотное написание

Tags: орфография

1. Возможны всё-таки оба варианта написания: "мучить" и "мучать"? "Помучаю" - только разговорный вариант? Пишем только "помучу"?
2. Встретилось в инете, что поменялось правило для прилагательного "ветреный". Как всё-таки правильно: "ветреный" или "ветренный"?
3. "Кушать" - это, действительно, моветон? А по отношению к маленьким детям, например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Мучить", "помучу", "ветреный".
2. Глагол "есть" употребляется в литературной речи (в том числе и в современной) несравненно шире своего синонима. 
   Глагол "кушать" можно употреблять как вежливое приглашение гостей, когда их сажают за стол. В этой ситуации используют инфинитив (кушать) -- в составе этикетной формулы “кушать подано, прошу к столу” или в повелительном наклонении — в составе другой формулы “кушайте, пожалуйста!”.

Но сейчас так практически не говорят, то есть стараются этот глагол избегать и чаще всего пользуются такими фразами, как “просим (или прошу) к столу” и т.п. Во всех других случаях - без исключения - мы должны пользоваться только глаголом "есть", например: я хочу есть, я уже поела, мы едим; ты ешь!

"Кушать" (равно как и глаголы покушать, скушать) может употребляться в обращении к детям: Ты кушал (покушал)? Хочешь кушать (покушать)? Скушай вот это. Покушай (скушай) что-нибудь и т. п. 
Использование глагола кушать в речи мужчин о себе (хочу кушать, я кушаю, я (не) кушал), а также когда мужчина или женщина говорит от имени четы или семьи: мы (уже) кушали (покушали), мы (не) хотим кушать и т. п., противоречит стилистической норме современного литературного языка, придаёт речи манерность, некоторую слащавость, квалифицируется как проявление мещанства в речи.

По существующему правилу глагол "кушать" используется только в повелительном наклонении и только при ласковом обращении к ребёнку, например: кушай, детка, не капризничай!

Но возникает вопрос: почему же в наше время очень часто современные русские люди пользуются глаголом кушать по отношению к себе и по отношению к близкому собеседнику? Хотя также замечено, что в нашей речи часто интуитивно замещается глагол есть другими глаголами, такими, как обедать, завтракать, ужинать.

И всё-таки нередко, говоря о себе, наши современники употребляют глагол кушать. С чем связана эта ошибка, откуда она берёт своё начало?

Начнём с того, что в русском языке 19 века глагол кушать встречался исключительно в речи прислуги, причём, употреблялся он не просто с оттенком вежливости, а, скорее всего, он имел оттенок учтивости, предупредительности и даже особо униженной вежливости. И, как правило, слуги, обращаясь к господам, говорили: “Кушать подано!” или – “Извольте кушать!”

И точно так же говорили лакеи или слуги о своих отсутствующих господах: “Клара Петровна сегодня дома не кушали”. И ещё заметим, что в нашем старинном просторечии (то есть исключительно в речи прислуги) применялись даже такие выражения, как ЧАЙ КУШАТЬ или КОФЕЙ КУШАТЬ.

И вот этот глагол "кушать" из языка прислуги, из лакейского лексикона во второй половине 19 века проник в русскую разговорную речь.

К примеру, известный писатель 1-й половины 20 века В.В. Бианки по этому поводу писал так: «Даже о себе мы начинаем говорить: я кушаю, мы кушаем. И получается смешновато: больно пышно» (Мысли вслух).

А Л. В. Успенский, известный писатель, автор многих популярных книг о русском языке, о слове "кушать" писал так: “…Не следует говорить “кушаю, кушаем” про самого себя; здесь обязательно простое “есть”, не содержащее в себе решительно никакого оттенка грубости, как чудится некоторым. Можно, но отнюдь не желательно употреблять глагол “кушать” в других лицах, и там вполне прилично обойтись нейтральным: “вы едите? А ты ешь раков?” и т.п. А всего лучше - просто исключить это лакейское словечко из своего языка”.

Но почему всё-таки глагол "кушать", если он так ограничен в своём употреблении, почему он довольно широко сейчас употребляется в нашей разговорной речи? Специалисты-языковеды считают, что это ложно понимаемая форма вежливости. То есть человек из ложной боязни выразиться грубо, прослыть невоспитанным человеком начинает включать в свою речь вместо глагола есть глагол кушать, который, по его мнению, относится к числу вежливых и не имеет грубого оттенка.

Таков механизм подмены глаголов "кушать" и "есть". Для русского литературного языка эта замена глаголов недопустима, то есть по существующему правилу нельзя говорить “я кушаю, ты кушаешь, мы кушаем”. По отношению к себе или по отношению к своему собеседнику (исключая маленького ребёнка) следует употреблять только глагол “есть”. Таков сложившийся обычай в русском языке.

Comment: *Таков сложившийся обычай в русском языке* — это, на мой взгляд, неверное утверждение, поскольку противоречит тому факту, что глагол "кушать" *довольно широко сейчас употребляется в нашей разговорной речи*. Скорее, такова НОРМА, с которой сложившийся обычай идёт вразрез.

Answer (score 4):

Кушать, безусловно, лакейское словечко, а в современной реальности или слащавое, или связанное с псевдокультурой. Таково его происхождение, и это пока еще ясно осознается более или менее образованными людьми.

Конечно, господа не ели, а кушали. Это же не столовая какая (котлета, гарнир, салат, компот), быстро съел и пошел дальше. Меню у них было разнообразное, каждое блюдо можно было только покушать, то есть попробовать, а потом перейти к другому. За обедом велись светские беседы, соблюдался этикет. Всё это наблюдала прислуга, убежденная в том, что "господа кушают".

Если посмотреть Нацкорпус до 1900 года, то форма кушаю/кушаем встречается крайне редко по сравнению с основным вариантом ем/едим, из чего можно сделать соответствующий вывод.  Также иногда создается впечатление, что слово "кушает" автор употребляет с иронией: "Николай Васильевич ведь нынче кушает с нами".

Comment: Vera, про кушать - сплошные эмоции и субъективизм. Господа вполне себе ели - и кушали тоже. Вот лакеи и холуи разделяли эти понятия, полагая, что гсопода только кушают. Вы сейчас эту ошибку воспроизводите.

Comment: Я просматриваю литературные тексты, делаю вывод о частотности и сфере употребления этих  слов и составляю пост, используя приемы публицистического стиля (а этот стиль всегда эмоционален). Но там, где высказано обычное мнение пользователя языка,  вы  почему-то усматриваете ошибочный субъективизм.

Comment: Ну частотностью обосновывать нормативность - это последнее дело. Вы же понимаете.

Comment: КУШАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. что. Есть, принимать пищу. Употр. в формулах вежливого приглашения к еде (в нормативной речи в 1 л. не употр.). К. подано! Пожалуйте к. Кушайте, пожалуйста! Кушай поскорее! (ребёнку). // Устар. Пить (чай, кофе, вино). Вопрос был задан о правильности этих  (уже существующих) норм. Изучение источников подтвердило обоснованность правила, совпадающего с моим собственным мнением.

Comment: ну и что? Я не возражаю.

Comment: Как же не возражаете? Вот же написали: "Кушать  - вполне нормальное и общелитературное слово. Предвзятое отношение возникло, видимо, под влиянием революционных масс, полагавших, что кушают только баре и недорезанные буржуи, а пролетариат и крестьянство едят".

Comment: И от этого не отказываюсь. Vera, давайте конкретнее. А то движок нас уже в чат отправляет. Какие мои тезисы по вашему мнению противоречат чему-то и чему конкретно?

Answer (score 1):

Мучить и разг. мучать. Если на письме вы передаете разговорную речь, возможно и помучаю.

Прилагательное ветреный пишется с одним н. Правила не менялись [(См. Академический справочник)](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=35#pp35).

[Как правильно: кушать или есть](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=750.j_nnPKJOf7b1q0dEXpSwx0gWhh6oMXmg5p_KZeUztRQYivsKAr2ElAmDDnbsbP1kwFILCKI4K2oAMW9T4xwZKwViOg7QjYMm4pLYSIlIRrCtTPxgHISOHwoG6cIIiKEE.0c58a23174ff9ca0caaab6f76608fb04ed70f7c3&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9bb4iM1VPfe4W5x0C0-qwflIRTTifi6VAA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBEZktJbU8ybXhCM3hINFFfRkxMVjRMakpCeFN5a2xad0pfelhUNnhIMlZCM1o2MFpyNWNMSU5TSjBGZERoNVNselM1c0Nua2UyR0g5TFFXeDBwekxuYTB5VmdTWWZoTGJVZmI5ejZZWmZWVQ&b64e=2&sign=240be235339dcae772bdab13fa22c420&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQbuVIyhUUbcoWjUsjz-jO6JFtqMiEKOdqHd27g4vx_3cHvFyY22XwFomJJPolyw3VGjy1nHeCVadN3RP72T0JM-YQ5ohnNJmHCgc4nhLj0UIHqxrVQLGzWpdT7Xh3acquxIGf68TuT-LtYL5c2SeddZXkxNzZ625sKmql-qZ_Ww9&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCTdwuV_bvPyfSQ3Wu39WHEQuhu8kJcY3-9D4MQJ-e8QNVA_QXe4bLBYtPt-hSRmaYDEH3xXY8oB-g4T40mMMfS-bKSusKzZe2nWiVOnU1fOciA9hFB0gclxNYTA7XOmUDa_Y4Q8KFeo8KUDWicERGipLsDrA9qUnwjY-BnUPI50mE-uh2jibWIMCTXU7eGAx2E63JWFTgMPn7ie9LqzzfcqPRtmG6IJhgR9RFN_kkXj1Vks2U96WKXki_xMaLyMwWE8X1BmeF_a3MxSOs9vKxCOgK-I1M31ASuLYeQ_P7VurX4d-WgcHVVvMGFRglDCOGjtLZbNFkTTg6qIH0sV-wON5mzJGsnFQeqWKHUnRakmw8SSDORlm0gJz1F3IkL7F9nQ-KkdPHJAYNiM53xD0Vrknpr7dAUiV4P1ub5uH2jPC9-Je7PZC7azaKo-rO_7H7uwEKANJWLGFU2dk148WlHxdlpam3HLAgG_8iBuOoMNUbvYomoiCetBs35aMogJJ5Vz20T7guMBhjPTKK7bXsW6HBiqGoRb390Hn-SExWOG3dye6wl9yj-w&l10n=ru&cts=1436952995549&mc=5.251643932968316)

Answer (score 1):

Слово "кушать" вовсе необязательно придает речи манерность или слащавость, когда используется и по отношению к взрослым. Возможно, такая коннотация присутствовала в 20-х годах, когда слово "кушать" считалось мелкобуржуазным, навевая ассоциации с "кушать изволите?" и т.п. А четким рабоче-крестьянским словом было "есть".

Но это было почти 100 лет назад.

КУШАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. что. Есть, принимать пищу. Употр. в формулах вежливого приглашения к еде (Словарь Кузнецова 1998 год) Никакого упоминания о слащавости.

Аналогично, мне кажутся надуманными слова о том, что это слово не употребляют по отношению к мужчинам. Можно регулярно услышать у носителей языка "Кушать будешь?" по отношению к гостю мужского пола, например. Особенно если это друг семьи. Слово при этом имеет неформальный, домашний оттенок. Или "подожди, он сейчас покушает" о муже, например.

Comment: Serg Z., в новом издании словаря Кузнецова говорится, что ''кушать" в нормативной речи в первом лице не употребляется.  Просто не все люди ощущают эту слащавость, манерность.

Comment: И далеко не все люди ее туда вкладывают. Поэтому ощущение того, чего там зачастую и нет - вещь субъективная. Так что подобная коннотация вовсе не обязательно присутствует. Я пишу именно об этом, а не о том, что ее там не бывает. Бывает, но это определяется контекстом, а также местными языковыми реалиями.

Comment: Sergе, если не ощущают, не значит, что нет.

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз мой пост. Я очень ясно высказался "Слово "кушать" вовсе необязательно придает речи манерность или слащавость". Слово необязательно в данном контексте означает, что манерность там может как быть так и отсутствовать. И зависит это от человека, который говорит и контекста. Уверен, что вы это понимаете, но просто случайно не заметили. :)

Comment: Николай, я прекрасно понимаю вашу мысль.  Я хочу сказать, что манерность, слащавость этом глаголе не субъективная вещь. Коннотация присутствует всегда. И от контекста она не зависит.

Comment: Дело не в том, что не употребляет, а в том, что по отношению к мужчинам и в в речи самих мужчин такое употребление некорректно. Просто не все носители языка об этом знают. Они употребляют этот глагол инстинктивно, не подозревая о коннотациях.

Comment: Почему женщины кушать могут, а мужчины нет? :)

Comment: И еще - вы в курсе, что коннотация зависит от контекста? Например, в тюрьме за слово "петушок", вас могут убить. А мама своего сына так может вполне называть, и никакой негативной коннотации и рядом не будет. Аналогично со словом "кушать".

Answer (score 1):

1. Мучить и мучить - равновозможны, здесь верю Аванесову.
   Соответственно - помучу и помучаю, последнее как минимум не менее правильно и более употребительно. 
   Есть другой подход, он предполагает что глагол "мучить" имеет неправильные личные формы, образованные от "не совсем нормативного" "мучать". 
   Тоже возможно.
2. Прилагательное (не причастие!) - ветреный, с одним н. Правило не менялось. Видимо речь идет о проекте изменений в орфографию, сделанном под руководством В. В. Лопатина. 
   Вот что он  сам говорит по этому поводу.

> Что касается принципиальных поправок, отметил Владимир Лопатин, то предлагается слово "ветреный" – прилагательное писать с двумя "н", как пишем все прилагательные с суффиксов "ен", образованные от имен существительных.

http://www.gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_187
Проект этот так и остался на бумаге.

3. "Кушать" - вполне нормальное и общелитературное слово. Предвзятое отношение возникло, видимо, под влиянием революционных масс, полагавших, что кушают только баре и недорезанные буржуи, а пролетариат и крестьянство едят. Что неверно, ибо есть (ясти) самое что ни на есть древнее слово, а "кушать" - более позднее. Как бы то ни было, в современном языке "кушать" менее распространено, с этим приходится считаться. Есть - нейтральное, а кушать - обычно стилистически окрашено.

Comment: А чем окрашено, какую дополнительную семантику "кушать" выражает? Вы сами-то едите или кушаете?

Comment: По контексту. Может быть детское, может быть стилизовано под старину, может быть подчеркнуто вежливое. А может быть и лакейское "кушать подано". Я согласен только в одном, в том, что современный представления предполагают "есть" нейтральным, а кушать - более экспрессивным, что ли...

Comment: В том-то и дело, что люди "кушают" совершенно в нейтральном стиле и даже не подозревают о какой-либо стилизованности.

Comment: Так а я о чем? Вы уж тогда четко сформулируйте, свою позицию - а потом меня пытайте. А то спор слепого с глухим получается.

Comment: Четкость изображения  предмета зависит и от наблюдателя тоже.